# this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'lms.Web.Models.ProductVM.ProductEditViewMode

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm creating asp .net core web application using Layered Architecture but when I am working with Edit action face that error. How can I solve the error?

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
   InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
   ViewDataDictionary is of type 'lms.Model.Product', but this
   ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
   'lms.Web.Models.ProductVM.ProductEditViewModel'.
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(object
   value)
```

```
**#ProductController**



     public IActionResult Edit(int id)
            {
               
    
               
                var prod = _productService.GetById(id);
    
                return View(prod);
            }
    
            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Edit(ProductEditViewModel model)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var product = _mapper.Map<Product>(model);
                    bool isSaved = _productService.Update(product);
    
                    if (isSaved)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                    }
    
    
                }
             
                
    
                return View();
            }

#ProductRepository

    public class ProductRepository:Repository<Product>,IProductRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public ProductRepository(ApplicationDbContext db) : base(db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
    
        public override ICollection<Product> GetAll()
        {
            return _db.Products.Include(c => c.Category).ToList();
        }
    
        public ICollection<Product> GetByCategory(int categoryId)
        {
            return _db.Products.Where(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId).ToList();
        }
    }


#ProductService
  

      private IProductRepository _productRepository;
            public ProductService(IProductRepository repository) : base(repository)
            {
                _productRepository = repository;
            }
    
            //public ICollection<Product> GetByYear(int year)
            //{
            //    throw new NotImplementedException();
            //}
    
            public ICollection<Product> GetByCategory(int categoryId)
            {
                var products = _productRepository.GetByCategory(categoryId);
    
                return products;
            }


#ProductEditViewModel


public class ProductEditViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> CategoryItemList { get; set; }


    //public ICollection<global::lms.Model.Product> ProductList { get; set; }
}

#EditView





    @model lms.Web.Models.ProductVM.ProductEditViewModel
    
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    }
    
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Edit">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input asp-for="IsActive" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsActive)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                        <select asp-for="CategoryId" asp-items="Model.CategoryItemList" class="form-control">
                            <option>Select...</option>
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Md Shariful Islam Shohag,this error message means your Edit action return view with type of `lms.Model.Product` model , but your edit view required type of `lms.Web.Models.ProductVM.ProductEditViewModel` model(your view defines `@model ProductEditViewModel`). The fontend and backend model do not match. Please keep the same.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix  get action

```
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
                 
var prod = _productService.GetById(id);
var categories= _categoryService.GetAll();
var categoryItemList=categories.Select(i=> new SelectListItem 
    {
    Value=i.Id.ToString(),
    Text=i.Name
    }).ToList();

var model = new ProductEditViewModel
{
    Name=prod.Name,
   Price= prod.Price,
   .... and so on
CategoryItemList = categoryItemList
}
      
return View(model);
}
```